# How to specify a “tab” in python code?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to write "welcome" TAB "username" in file.
 How can I specify this TAB?

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write("welcome:"+TAB+"username");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\t` character:

```
>>> print('\tsomething')
    something
```

In your case that would be

```
f.write("welcome:\tusername")
```

Comment: Just for sake of completeness, you can also use `chr(9)`, `9` being the ASCII code of the `TAB` character.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
f.write("welcome:\tusername")
```